# C++ passing const value of derived class to constructor of base unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, constants, initialization-order

I assume this is fairly basic, but I couldn't find any source here.

A derived class contains initialization information which needs to be passed to the base class. In this case it is a memory reservation.

```
class Derived: public Base
{
private:
  const unsigned short memorySize= 100;    
public:  
  inline Derived() : Base(memorySize) {}
  void DoStuff();
};
```

This fails miserably. I expect the base constructor is called before the derived constructor, and memorySize is only assigned when the derived constructor is being called.

```
#define memorySize 100

class Derived: public Base
{
private:

public:  
  inline Derived() : Base(memorySize) {}
  void DoStuff();
};
```

This works as expected.

My questions: 
Is my assumption that memorySize in the first example has not yet been initialized at the time the base constructor is being called, or is something else happening here?

I have learned that #define for constants are undesirable in C++, and it's highly preferable to use const values. Is this an exception to this rule, or is there a more proper way to deal with this situation?

Comment: On top of the correct answer already posted, yes, base class(es) are always initialized *before* class members are initialized, so `memorySize` is uninitialized when passed to `Base` constructor.

Comment: you should enable your compiler warnings. The compiler should be able to diagnose this.

Comment: Compiler warnings are on, but I'm stuck with a framework which does the absolute bare minimum to help me. But you are right, I should urgently change to another system.

Comment: @Micha Hmm, I checked. GCC fails to diagnose this bug. Bug clang does diagnose by default.

Comment: @eerorika using g++ but with MPLAB X, which can be really unclear in compiler warnings and such. At times I don't get whats happening anymore and I decide to restart MPLAB, after the restart all compiler errors are suddenly gone, and it compiles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two examples are entirely incomparable. In the first example, every instance of `Derived` gets its own copy of `memorySize`. As you guessed, the constructor of `Derived` takes care of that.

You don't want that at all. There's only one constant for the class, not a separate constant for every instance. That's written as

```
class Derived: public Base
{
private:
  static const unsigned short memorySize = 100;
```

Comment: Thank you! That works indeed. But for me it raises another question: As the constants are being constant, they will be the same in every instance of the class anyway. Why are they not being declared static automatically?

Comment: @Micha The fact that it's constant doesn't imply that it will be the same in every object of this class. You can initialize it differently for every single object (and after initialization it will be immutable for this object). [See an example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iF8KtCwpBajv7B4d)

Comment: @Micha because it's only a defauly value to be used, you can still initialize it with a different value in a constructor initialization list